# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta de datos más rápido para una página web?

Tags: base-de-datos, web, optimización, carga, consultar

esta es una pregunta técnica, no es sobre códigos.

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de optimizar una consulta de datos para una web?
Por ejemplo, un blog va a mostrar un artículo, y la duda es cuál es el tipo de consulta que va más rápido al recuperar el contenido del artículo (todo el texto, imágenes, fecha, autor etc) entre una consulta a una base de datos MySQL, o llamar un archivo JSON, o incluir un archivo PHP.

Haciendo pruebas con Google Page Speed Insights he visto que una consulta MySQL antes de empezar a cargar el código HTML hace que la página web tarde bastante en cargarse. Entre estas tres opciones no sé cuál es la mejor, la más optimizada ni las buenas prácticas con este asunto ni por qué ¿alguien me lo podría explicar?

Gracias y un saludo a tod@s.

Answer (score 2):

En la realidad vas a tener que probar el tiempo de consulta con cada forma de almacenar tu data para encontrar la optima.

Pero, **en mi opinion** depende de la data y lo que deseas hacer esta.

Un JSON siempre va a ser lo mas directo cuando quieres tratar con data por lo que si tu data es pequeña y tu consulta es solo de lectura puedes usarlo.

pero tiene multiples desventajas, principalmente vas a tener que asegurarte de no tener una [Condición de carrera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condici%C3%B3n_de_carrera) por lo que vas a tener que implementar tus propios [bloqueos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

Además vas a tener que mover la logica de la data de la base de datos al backend por ejemplo asegurarte de que el nombre de una persona no tiene simbolos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Miguel, JSON es el formato que está más preparado para este tipo de consultas, la desventaja que le veo a JSON es que hay que hacer una consulta al script y eso consume tiempo de carga, pero mucho menos que una consulta a una base de datos MySQL.